# Objective-C accessors also available without @synthesize

Tags: objective-c, setter, getter, synthesize

Consider following code:

```
@interface TestClass ()

@property NSString *privateProperty;

@end
```

Now, as I learned, to make to compiler also create the accessors, I have to add the @synthesize directive in the @implement-part.

But also, if don't add the directive, following message works:

```
[self setPrivateProperty:@"foo"];
```

From my understanding, this should lead to an error explaining me, that the selector is unknown. Why does this setter (and I think also the getter) still exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since xcode 4.5 all properties will be synthesized automagically.

Comment: Actually, this is not a new feature of Xcode. It is a new feature of the LLVM compiler that happens to come with newer versions of Xcode. You lose this feature if you tell Xcode to use a different compiler. You also get this feature without Xcode if you compile your code with the LLVM compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The `@property` declaration declares the existence of the getter and setter methods. The `@synthesize` declaration creates implementations of those methods.

Before Xcode 4.5, you'd have got a compiler warning for omitting the `@synthesize` and a runtime crash - both caused by there being no implementation for the methods you'd implicitly declared.

As of Xcode 4.5, the implementation of the methods is automatically synthesized unless you specify otherwise (`@dynamic`).

Answer (score 0):

It's a new feature introduced in a recent version of XCode: it auto-syntetize the property, creating an _propertyName ivar to store it.